# Check remote port access using Delphi - Telnet style

Tags: delphi, telnet, indy

I deploy my application in environments heavily stricken with firewalls. Frequently I find myself using Telnet to check if a port is open and accessible in the network.
Now I would like to implement an equivalent functionality of the command, `Telnet [domainname or ip] [port]`, in Delphi.

1. Is it adequate that I just attempt to open and close a TCP/IP socket without sending or receiving any data?
2. Is there any risk that I might crash the arbitrary application/service listening on the other end?

Here's my code:

```
function IsPortActive(AHost : string; APort : Word):boolean;
var IdTCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
begin
  IdTCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      IdTCPClient.Host := AHost;
      IdTCPClient.Port := APort;
      IdTCPClient.Connect;

    except
      //Igonre exceptions
    end;

  finally
    result := IdTCPClient.Connected;
    IdTCPClient.Disconnect;
    FreeAndNil(IdTCPClient);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This code disconnects even if the client is disconnected. And finally should only be used for resource cleanup (IdTCPClient.Free is all I would put there).

Comment: Why do you want to know this information ? Btw. there is the `TIdTelnet` client component if you'd like to act as a Telnet client. Anyway, you might write a [`code like this`](http://pastebin.com/tLsw3KwL) since when the connection cannot be established, an exception will be raised.

Comment: @TLama TIdTelnet expects a real Telnet server. Connect might block "forever" with a non-compliant server. If the code is meant to be a replacement "using Telnet to check if a port is open and accessible in the network", this might not be the expected behavior.

Comment: @mjn, that's right. I should have phrase that more carefully... :)

Comment: It really depends what your application is doing. You'd better off fail and provide detailed diagnostic info, having network admin probe dat port for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check whether the port is open, then you can use this:

```
function IsPortActive(AHost : string; APort : Word): boolean;
var
  IdTCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    IdTCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      IdTCPClient.Host := AHost;
      IdTCPClient.Port := APort;
      IdTCPClient.Connect;
      Result := True;
    finally
      IdTCPClient.Free;
    end;
  except
    //Ignore exceptions
  end;
end;
```

But that only tells you if *any* server app has opened the port.  If you want to make sure that YOUR server app opened the port, then you will have to actually communicate with the server and make sure its responses are what you are expecting.  For this reason, many common server protocols provide an initial greeting so clients can identify the type of server they are connected to.  You might consider adding a similar greeting to your server, if you are at liberty to make changes to your communication protocol.

Simply opening a connection to the server does not impose any risk of crashing the server, all it does is momentarily occupy a slot in the server's client list.  However, if you actually send data to the server, and the server app you are connected to is not your app, then you do run a *small* risk if the server cannot handle arbitrary data that does not conform it its expected protocol.  But that is pretty rare.  Sending a small command is not uncommon and usually pretty safe, you will either get back a reply (which may be in a format that does not conform to your protocol, so just assume failure), or you may not get any reply at all (like if the server is waiting for more data, or simply is not designed to return a reply) in which case you can simply time out the reading and assume failure.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Remy! I observe that you free the object directly without first calling the Disconnect proc. Will the connection be disconnected gracefully, i.e. will the server remove the slot from its client list?

Comment: Yes. `TIdTCPConnection.Destroy()` closes the socket the same way `TIdTCPClient.Disconnect()` does - by calling `TIdIOHandler.Close()`. Calling `Disconnect()` after `Connect()` in this example is OK but redundant.

Comment: unfortunately this not working for me, if port and ip is available on network it return `true` but if ip or port not available, the program crashed.i tried to add `timeout` property to `IdTCPClient` but dont helped me!!

Comment: @peimanF. It does not crash, it simply raises an exception, there is a difference. That is why the code has a `try..except` block

Comment: my mistake , i mean hang when i said crash.i used this code and when the port and ip is ok it return true but when there is a problem the function dont return any think until all application hanged!! for this i tried to add timeout but not worked at all!!

Comment: @peimanF. On which platform? The `ConnectTimeout` works fine on Windows, might not work on some other platforms. It is implemented using a thread to open the connection and closes the socket if the thread times it. Not all platforms support aborting a blocked socket operation by closing the socket in another thread.